# Inline horizontal spacer in HTML

Tags: html

I am making a Web page with a slideshow, using the same technique used on http://zine.pocoo.org/. The person I'm making the site for wants the slideshow to be centered. However, some of the photos are portrait layout and some are landscape. (This was not my choice.) I need a `position: absolute` to get the li's containing the items in the right place, so centering them does not work. (At least, not by normal methods.)

So, I thought that it might work to insert a 124-pixel "spacer" before the image on the portrait pictures. I tried it with a `<span style="width: 124px;">&nbsp;</span>`, but it only inserts a single space, not the full 124 pixels. The slideshow fades in and out OK, though, so I think that it would work if I could get the proper spacing.

My question is this: does anyone know a way to have 124px of space **inline** in HTML (preferably without using images), or another way to center the pictures in the `li` items?

Comment: Actually, I just ended up adding a `style="padding-left: 124px;"` attribute to the `<img />` tags. Still, if anyone else can answer this question, it would be pretty useful in the future.

Comment: There is no spacer element in HTML. This is because HTML is meant to semantically mark up your content, and spacing is presentational.

The correct way to do it is with CSS, either using padding on the containing <li>, or margins on the <img> as TrueSoft suggests in his answer.

Comment: Padding or margin is working great if you have an access to html attribute inside of html tag, here for example is <img>, but if you can't modify attribute or apply a css to it, then something like <span style="width:21px;float:right">&nbsp;</span> is still a solution. Notice, you may use float:left or right depending where you want your spacer.

Answer (score 4):

This is way old, but I guess it's still worth answering. The reason your span isn't expanding is because it's still an inline element. set display:inline-block to get it to behave more like a block element

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `margin-left` instead of `padding-left`, because the margin is outside an element, and the padding is inside.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid putting large spacers on elements and especially on multiple elements. The only way to add a spacer on your element would be relative positioning or an inline-block element (use carefully.)

Your best bet for the slideshow is to have a relative positioned `<ul>`. Since the `<ul>` is relative positioned you can set the `<li>`s to be `position:absolute;` within the `<ul>`. At this point you can set the `<li>`s to `width:100%;` and `text-align:center;` so that anything inside is positioned in the horizontal center (vertical centering in CSS2 is tricky.) Check out http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ which outputs inline styling by default but is still really nice.